# Install R in ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I try to install R in ubuntu using this in terminal console:

```
deb https://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu yakkety/
```

in my case

```
deb https://<http://cran.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CRAN/>/bin/linux/ubuntu yakkety/
```

but I receive that no such file or directory. What can I do to type right the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line should be

```
deb https://cran.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu yakkety/
```

But don't run it in the terminal.  It needs to be added to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

If you carefully follow the instructions at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README, you should have no problems.

Comment: thank I made it using `sudo nano etc/apt/sources.list` to add in this file the path howerver after that I can't open again this file even it is exist in sources when I type in terminal it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: @teletab - It needs to be `/etc/...`, with the leading `/`.  Very important ;)